# webclient download progress

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using web client to download files from the server in myC#/WPF program. I am subscribing to DownloadProgressChanged and DownloadDataCompleted events of the WebClient class. The problem is while trying to download some files i am getting the BytesRecieved value as -1. I am getting proper values for some files when downloaded from same server.

Any idea why is this behavior?